# nodejs API query how to access data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using aws-lib to retrieve data from the Amazon affiliate API on my server.

```
    var aws = require("../lib/aws");

prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey, yourAssociateTag);

prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", {SearchIndex: "Books", Keywords: "Javascript"}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
})
```

This console.logs a huge JSON document with multiple objects, I now require the ability to call these objects with angular on my client side. I have been using app.get and $http.get with mongojs to retrieve local MongoDB database data can I use a similar method? I tried to post it a MongoDB database with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/amazon', function (req, res){
  prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey, yourAssociateTag);

  prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", {SearchIndex: "Books", Keywords: "Javascript"}, function(err, result) {
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Then, on the client side you could do that :

```
$http.get("http://domain:port/amazon")
  .then(function(response) {
    //do whatever you want 
});
```

Comment: sorry, I only showed how i currently get my games database, the data being pulled from Amazon is not that data. I don't know how to use that data.

Comment: Please add how you accessing the data from amazaon

Comment: I am not really understanding your problem.You managed to pull data from amazon, right? Then, with that data, what do you want to do? Pass it to the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have two ways to present data sent from the node.js server :

- **Ajax** : something like : `$.get('/games',function(res){ // res holds the data });`
- **Template** : eg EJS : something like : `<%= data %>`
  find more about ejs : 
  http://www.embeddedjs.com/